# Replace a series of if/else-if/else statements that increment seven variables in an array of integers

Tags: java, bluej

I need to replace a series of if/else-if/else statements that increment seven integers with a single statement that increments the appropriate integer in the collection.
I have an array of integers intialised:

```
    int[] finals={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

I don't know how to access the index of and modify the different variables in the list.
This is Java BTW.

Comment: `finals[2] = 1;` what is your question?

Answer (score 3):

to access the variables in the array:

`int[] finals={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};`

```
finals[0] = 1;
finals[1] = 2;
```